# Opertion Not permitted docker and python configuration

Tags: python, docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to build an image using Nginx as base image. Below is the docker file I'm using to install python in the image.

```
FROM nginx:stable

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.2/Python-3.10.2.tgz
RUN tar -xvf Python-3.10.2.tgz
RUN cd Python-3.10.2 && ./configure --enable-optimization
```

When it comes to ./configure I'm getting error like below

```
ls: . : Operation not permitted
```

What is the possible way to run configure?

Comment: Can you start your image `FROM python:3.10` instead; why use Nginx as the base image here?

Comment: I'm using nginx here because further commands require nginx configured as part of the docker image. Python is needed for the initial app build.

Comment: If that's all you need it for, a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) could make sense: have a first stage `FROM python`, and then a final stage `FROM nginx` that copies the built artifacts from the initial stage.